# How do I use python reverse() function to pass list of ids as query parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-admin

I need to generate a URL with a list of object ids as query params.
i.e
Url will look something like `admin/app/model/?id__in=1,2,3`.
I have used `reverse('admin:app_model_changelist', kwargs={id__in:<list_of_ids>})` which doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`reverse()`** won't generate query params. You can just try the string formatting as

```
path = reverse('admin:app_model_changelist')
result = '%s?id__in=%s' % (path, ','.join(map(str,list_of_ids)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `kwargs` you will have to provide a dictionary with the named arguments, as specified in your URL configuration.

Try instead to use `args`, like described in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/) on `resolve()`:

> If the URL accepts arguments, you may pass them in args. For example:
>
> ```
> from django.urls import reverse
>
> def myview(request):
>    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('arch-summary', args=[1945]))
> ```